# `unknown provider` error if not using global app variable

Tags: angularjs

I have three different application files (in addition to vendor files) for my angular app loaded in this order

```
app.js
store.js
controller.js
```

The code from the different files is only visible to the others if I'm using a global variable, however, I thought if I used modules by starting each file like this

```
angular.module('myApp',
```

then I could avoid a global and have code defined in each file available to the others.

Example

if I do it this way with the global variable `myApp` then the storage provider is available in the controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['LocalStorageModule'])
      .config(['localStorageServiceProvider',
           function(localStorageServiceProvider) {
              localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('my-app');
        }]);

myApp.factory('myStorage', 
      //code ommitted

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', [$scope, 'myStorage',
      function MyController($scope, myStorage){

      }
]);
```

However, if in the three files, I instead do it this way (without the global) then I get an `unknownProvider` error in `myCtrl`

```
          angular.module('myApp', ['LocalStorageModule'])
              .config(['localStorageServiceProvider',
               function(localStorageServiceProvider) {
                  localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('my-app');
          }]);

         angular.module('myApp', [])
             .factory('myStorage', 
          //code omitted
         angular.module('myApp', [])
           .controller('MyCtrl', [$scope, 'myStorage',
             function MyController($scope, myStorage){

              }
            ]);
```

Question: IN the example above, how can I make the storage from the factory available in the controller without using the global variable pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only define module once, and use it in rest of the places. Otherwise it gets overwritten. Please remove the dependency array from module definition for factory & controller. Hope that helps.

```
angular.module('myApp')
             .factory('myStorage', 
          //code omitted
         angular.module('myApp')
           .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'myStorage',
             function ($scope, myStorage){

              }
            ]);
```

Also your controller declaration is needs to be corrected as above.

Answer (score 1):

The Best way to inject any service, factory etc... this way reduce Complicity...

```
`angular.module('myApp')
         .factory('myStorage', 
      //code omitted
     angular.module('myApp')
       .controller('MyCtrl', myCtrlFun);
      myCtrlFun.$inject = ['$scope', 'myStorage'];

      function myCtrlFun($scope, myStorage){

      }
```

`